# Open-source cross-platform XMPP client with native OTR support

Tags: linux, open-source, cross-platform, encryption, xmpp

I'm looking for an open-source XMPP client that

- works on Linux, but also other systems,
- has native OTR support (doesn't require plugins)
- and of course, **has a nice UI**.

I have used **Tor Messenger** and it was the best client I have used so far.
Nice design, OTR support, cross-platform. However the latest version is seriously bugged.

**Pidgin** has no OTR support and to be honest, awful UI. Same goes with Instantbird (even though Tor Messenger is based on it, the *native* UI is awful and lacks OTR support).

Edit: Pidgin might be the best option, the OTR plugin is made by the same people who made OTR and it has a good plugin support in general. The UI is something I will have to get used to.

Comment: maybe useful: https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/software.php

Comment: `cross-platform`, for what platforms? Btw what's ugly about Pidgin? Pidgin just uses your GTK theme…

Comment: @wb9688 I didn't mean the GTK part, but just the UI - the layout. But I guess it's not *too* bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pidgin was your best shot for cross-platform, and while the OTR support comes from a plugin, it's still there. I can't make any recommendations to make the UI better, though, and it is pretty craptacular.

But there are other applications with OTR support, or plugins that allow you to add OTR support to other clients. See https://otr.im/clients.html for a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Kadu](http://www.kadu.im/w/English:Main_Page) - it:

- Is an open source Gadu-Gadu and Jabber/XMPP protocol Instant Messenger client for Linux, BSD, Mac OS X and Windows.
- Has OTR support since version 2.0 *possibly earlier*
- Runs on Linux, BSD, Mac & Windows
- **Has no adware**
- Looks to have a decent user interface

From the web page:

[image: Screenshot]